# Exporting SQL Server 2014 database data into a Microsoft Office Word 2010 document

Tags: sql-server, ms-word

What I got:

- An SQL Server database with x amount of tables
- An empty Word 2010 document

What I would like to achieve:

- To fill the empty Word document with data from a specific table in my database.

What I've tried so far:

- Microsoft Office guide to import data using the Data Connection Wizard (found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/import-data-into-office-publisher-visio-or-word-by-using-the-data-connection-wizard-HA010209005.aspx))

This didn't work out very well for me and I'm not very sure why.

### Question

Am I approaching this in the right manner with the Data Connection Wizard, or am I missing out on something less complicated and more suiting of my needs?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. Assuming that you want to use the data writing a document and do it more often than once (so automated) you can execute one of the following:

- "For the knowledgeable": create a SQL script that spits out RTF (or maybe even XML for docx) and open the RTF in Word. The SQL script can of course be encapsulated in a web page or exe. Note that is can be quite hard to get tables right. Try to stick to TAB-s.
- "From within Word": we use ourselves our own product [Invantive Composition](http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-composition) (free version available for download). You enter the view or table names as blocks in the template designer (modeller ribbon) and press Publish in the end user ribbon.
- "The BI way": use a program such as [iReports](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/) or Crystal Reports or Access, and write a report that you save as RTF, doc or docx.

Comment: hi @Marcus Did any of these answers help you solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try SQL Workbench. I've always had great success with it, they also feature exports as CSV if I'm not mistaken. Read more [here](http://www.sql-workbench.net).

Comment: It doesn't seem to support exporting to Word, what I can tell.

Comment: @Marcus well probably not per se, but Word does support importing csv files afaik.